# Extra long descriptive paragraph

Tags: novel

This is one person describing the past behavior of another, who is absent, to two different people. One of the listeners knows the person who is being spoken about. It's just a long dialogue describing the history of that person.What that person did a long time back, to make the teller dislike that person. Do I let other people listening say something? Do I use a period in different places throughout and start a new paragraph in places throughout the dialogue?Though it is still about the same person? There are more than one hundred and fifty words in this entire paragraph. But it needs to be said. How do I make it readable and not just a 'run-on' sentence? Sincerely A..
,

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Writers. Stack Exchange is not like other sites. We are a Q&A site, not a discussion board or an online workshop. This is close to being a good question — general "How do I accomplish X?" questions are on-topic — but from your specific example, the community can't help you. You've already listed some good techniques to break up a gray wall of text, and anything else we could suggest would be editing your specific work, which is off-topic here.

Comment: Can you seriously just space your full stops right? It's impossible to read

Comment: I think this could easily become a good question. There are often moments when a writer needs to have a character expose something and that can easily turn into a boring 'history lesson' (whether it's historical events or not). The other option is often to have the narrator do telling, ehich is even worse. I much prefer to have a character do the exposition but in a rich environment that will allow for something else to be happenning in the background at the same time as the exposition is happening. By varying the techniques, it can even become an interesting scene.

Comment: Personally, I find long descriptive paragraphs to be boring.  In Lord of the Rings for example, I would often skip several paragraphs when he would describe the city or environment at the start of chapters.  A lot of it can be done while you go through the story and doesn't need to be a pure paragraph strictly to describe something.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to answer a generalist version of this question:

> How to deal with a rather long dialogue paragraph?

First of all, you must decide if you really want to have a single person talking non-stop. Personally I don't advise it.

Secondly, break it up and use one (or some) of the techniques below.

1. You can have the other people intervene with comments like 'Oh, dear! What did you do?' or 'I'd never speak to him again'.
2. You can have other people, outside the dialogue, interrupt with an accidental bump that'll cause a glass to spill and will force the group to move to a more quiet place. Or, if it's at a restaurant, let the waiter come in and the people either show they're not so interested by happily turning to the waiter, or show their interest by shooing the waiter with a 'we're not ready to order yet. We'll call you.'.
3. If the narrator is one of the listening people, you can interrupt the dialogue with their thoughts on particular events being mentioned, or maybe that one person has half his mind on the conversation and the other half is worried about his son who's gone to prom and he better not be drinking because he's supposed to be the designated driver for his friends.

By breaking up the long dialogue paragraph, you avoid boring the reader and get the chance to point at what else is going on, in the area or in the other characters' minds.

Comment: +1) All of the above, plus action mono/dialog tags--the person talking sips her/his drink, adjusts her hair, checks his zipper, etc.--then keeps monologuing to her/his heart content :-)

Answer (score 1):

As Lauren pointed out, you have more than one question in your post. I will take a stab at one of them before the whole thing gets off-topic-ed.

> Do I use a period in different places throughout and start a new paragraph in places throughout the dialogue?Though it is still about the same person?

Yes. The common punctuation (in American English) is:

> "**Open a quotation**, then write, write, write, and write. You can break the speech up into sentences and use periods and any other punctuation marks (to avoid run-ons). When you feel that you need to start a new paragraph: **do not close the quotation** (still the same person talking)...
>
> "**Open another quotation**, start a new paragraph and keep writing. You can do it as many times as you wish. When you are done with that person talking, **close the quotation**."

It is, however, only for you to decide if you want to interrupt the monolog with tags or somebody else's remarks, turning it into a dialog.